# To check whether the series is convergent or not $\frac{1}{4\times6}+ \frac{\sqrt3}{6\times8}+\frac{\sqrt5}{8\times10}+\dots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\frac{1}{4\times6}+ \frac{\sqrt3}{6\times8}+\frac{\sqrt5}{8\times10}+\dots$$

The general formula for this that I got is : $$\sum_{n=4}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n-3}}{n(n+2)}$$

the problem I am facing is that I am not able to choose the correct test, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your formula is erroneous if you do not add that $n$ is even.

Comment: @JeanMarie thanks for informing me about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want to check convergence of $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{2n-1}}{(2n+2)(2n+4)}$. $p$-series test says

- If $p<-1$, then $\sum n^p$ converges.
- If $p\ge -1$, then $\sum n^p$ diverges.

$\sum n^{-3/2}$ converges, and you may compare $\frac{\sqrt{2n-1}}{(2n+2)(2n+4)}$ with $cn^{-3/2}$, where $c$ is constant.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have to mention that $n$ above is even, but I claim that does not matter: even if you include odd $n$, the series is convergent, so that it anyway is convergent in the even case.

Note that $\frac{\sqrt{n-3}}{n(n+2)} \leq \frac{\sqrt n}{n^2} = \frac 1{n^{1.5}}$ as the numerator has become bigger, but the denominator has got smaller. Thus, we have a new sequence $\sum_4^\infty \frac 1{n^{1.5}}$. This is known to be convergent by the p-series test, however it's explicit bound is the integral $\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac 1{n^{1.5}}$, which you can evaluate for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

With *equivalents*:

The simplest formula for this series is
$\;\displaystyle\sum_{n\ge 2}\frac{\sqrt{2n-3\mathstrut}}{4n(n+1)}.$

Now the general term is
$$\frac{\sqrt{2n-3\mathstrut}}{4n(n+1)}\sim_\infty\frac{\sqrt{2n\mathstrut}}{(2n)^2}=\frac{1}{(2n)^{3/2}}, $$
which is a convergent *Riemann series*.

Comment: wouldn't the series you mentioned will be $\frac{1}{8.3}+\frac{\sqrt(3)}{12.4}+\frac{\sqrt(5)}{16.5}+...$ and this is not the series which I mentioned.

Comment: The series you mention in your title has no odd factor in the denominator. The general formula you give has. I referred to the series in title.